# Unable to checkout a branch with repo tool

Tags: git, repo

I'm trying to check out a branch using `repo` tool. The steps I'm following are:

1. initialize the repository

   repo init -u https://meh
2. sync it

   repo sync
3. start master for all projects

   repo start master --all

Now one of the repositories looks like this:

```
*   4d35068 4 hours ago (user1)         (HEAD, m/master, git-server/master, master)   Merge branch 'BUG-1234' into 'master'
|\                                                                  
| |                                                                 
| * 5f5bef7 4 hours ago (user1)         (git-server/BUG-1234)   BUG-1234: fixing something
| |                                                                 
* | 86aa598 4 hours ago (user2)           BUG-1235: Bug fixing      
| |                                                                 
* | 9a5511d 5 hours ago (user2)           BUG-1235: fixing something
| |                                                                 
| |                                                                 
* | 6a9a6c5 5 hours ago (user2)           BUG-1235: fixing something 
|/                                                                  
|                                                                   
* 33d9c96 7 hours ago (user2)     BUG-1235: fixing code
```

4. Try to checkout branch BUG-1234 with

   repo checkout BUG-1234

The issue im facing at this point iss that HEAD is not pointing to `5f5bef7` as i would expect, but to `4d35068`

```
*   4d35068 4 hours ago (user1)         (HEAD, m/master, git-server/master, topbeat-b1, master, BUG-1234)   Merge branch 'BUG-1234' into 'master'
|\                                                                  
| |                                                                 
| * 5f5bef7 4 hours ago (user1)         (git-server/BUG-1234)   BUG-1234: fixing something
| |                                                                 
* | 86aa598 4 hours ago (user2)           BUG-1235: Bug fixing      
| |                                                                 
* | 9a5511d 5 hours ago (user2)           BUG-1235: fixing something
| |                                                                 
| |                                                                 
* | 6a9a6c5 5 hours ago (user2)           BUG-1235: fixing something 
|/                                                                  
|                                                                   
* 33d9c96 7 hours ago (user2)     BUG-1235: fixing code
```

I think I haven't told `repo` tool how to map the two branches but I'm not sure if/how I can do that.

---

Expected result after `repo checkout BUG-1234`:

```
*   4d35068 4 hours ago (user1)         (HEAD, m/master, git-server/master, topbeat-b1, master)   Merge branch 'BUG-1234' into 'master'
|\                                                                  
| |                                                                 
| * 5f5bef7 4 hours ago (user1)         (git-server/BUG-1234, BUG-1234)   BUG-1234: fixing something
| |                                                                 
* | 86aa598 4 hours ago (user2)           BUG-1235: Bug fixing      
| |                                                                 
* | 9a5511d 5 hours ago (user2)           BUG-1235: fixing something
| |                                                                 
| |                                                                 
* | 6a9a6c5 5 hours ago (user2)           BUG-1235: fixing something 
|/                                                                  
|                                                                   
* 33d9c96 7 hours ago (user2)     BUG-1235: fixing code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`repo checkout BUG-1234` will create a local branch based on local branch `master'.

Please use the following command to create local branch to track remote branch.

> git checkout --track git-server/BUG-1234

By the way, you can use the following command to check whether your local branch is tracking a remote branch.

> git branch -a -vv